Another werewolf "kill the source" movie identification
Around the mid 2000s, I saw a werewolf movie that was probably made in the 90s by the look of the film. Maybe a B movie. I have searched all over google and werewolf sites and can't find it. Here is what it is about, to the best of my memory:
The movie starts out with a bunch of people at a party (maybe at a beach?). A guy (guy #1) gets bitten by a werewolf. The next day, or shortly thereafter, he meets another guy (guy #2) who was bitten by the same werewolf at an earlier date. Guy #2 has been searching for the werewolf that bit him in order to remove the curse before he completely turns into a werewolf. Guy #1 and #2 drive around looking for the werewolf. At one point, they stop at a restaurant and guy #2 orders his steak rare because he is starting to like the taste of blood. At some point in the movie, a girl shows up who was also bitten by the same werewolf. All of the lead characters were in their early 20s.
That is all my memory has of the movie. In short:

Party where lead character is bitten.
Lead meets other character bitten by the same source, and he likes rare steaks.
They drive around in an old car.
They meet a girl who was also bitten by the same source (maybe a sister to one of them?)
I think they kill the source with silver?


Very very similar to The Forsaken but it was a vampire not a werewolf.

Sean is driving cross-country to deliver a vintage Mercedes and attend his sister's wedding when he picks up hitchhiker Nick, who just happens to be a vampire hunter, tracking down a group of youthful vampires who feed on unwary travelers. They run into Megan, who has been left for dead by the vampires. As they use her as a lure for the vampires, Sean becomes attracted to her. After Sean is infected with the vampire virus, he, Megan and Nick must race against time to kill the vampire leader Kit to stop Sean from becoming one of the undead.




